# Second order uniformly elliptic operators in 1-dimension

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Can you provide an example of a second order uniformly elliptic operator in 1D other than the classical Laplace operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $1$-D all second order uniformly elliptic operators are of the form:$$ Lu = -a(x)u''(x)+b(x)u'(x)+c(x)u(x)$$ with $$a(x)\geqslant \lambda x^2$$ for some $\lambda>0$. Hence, just pick $a$ different from $1$, satisfying the above condition and you have your answer.